# How do I use a regular expression to "Find and Replace" in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file which has 6000+ text entries like this:

```
<"+88016000000" time="Dec 5, 2018 2:36:03 PM" date="1543998963051" type="1" body="I am Noushin,studying  BBA final year." read="1" service_center="+8801801000016" name="" />
```

I need to keep the phone number and `body` attributes like the following:

```
+88016000000 I am Noushin,studying  BBA final year.
```

How would I write a regular expression to use in the "Find and Replace" feature of Notepad++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use named capture groups to get the values of the attributes you want to keep. Here's a pattern that works on the example you provided. [Pattern proof](https://regex101.com/r/sLVHuK/1).

**Find what:**

```
<"(?<phone>\+\d+)".*?body="(?<body>[^"]*)".*?>
```

The phone number is now available via the `phone` capture group, and the text via the `body` capture group. Reference these groups to keep the values you want.

**Replace with:**

```
$+{phone} $+{body}
```

[image: Original text]

[image: Find and replace box]

[image: Result]

**Edit**

If you're looking for an attribute called `address` instead of an anonymous attribute at the beginning of the tag, you can use the following:

```
<.*?address="(?<phone>\+\d+)".*?body="(?<body>[^"]*)".*?>
```

Comment: some data can't do .please check it .

Answer (score 0):

```
<sms address="+8801954670592" time="Dec 20, 2018 12:39:04 PM" date="1545287944954" type="1" body="Interested in rampura bajar class 12, 4 days, ICT and Math, 4000" read="1" service_center="+88019900557" name="" />

<sms address="MobileTV" time="Dec 20, 2018 2:36:08 PM" date="1545294968640" type="1" body="Live watch sports and entertainment TV please visit http://wap.teletalk.com.bd/?t=aiMsX first month subscription free!!" read="1" service_center="+880150159966" name="cn n okok" />
```

I Just need first one don't need 2nd

Comment: Added a new pattern to the bottom of my original answer. It will find phone numbers in the `address` attribute and will ignore text in the `address` attribute.